# Refresh ImageView from URL Android

Tags: java, android, url, imageview, refresh

I need some help. I want to refresh my ImageView loaded from a URL in my android app. I try use timers but doesn't work. Any thoughts?

I have this code in Main Activity:

```
public class Imagens extends Activity {

private ImageView imagem;
private Bitmap bit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imagens);
    imagem=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    bit=getBitmapFromURL("http://www.onlinedegrees.org/wp-content/uploads/android1.jpg");
    imagem.setImageBitmap(bit);
}
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src){
    try{
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

And in the AndroidManifest uses:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

to allow internet connection.

Comment: Means your image need to again download from another url right?

Comment: check my below answer. have you checked it??

Comment: From the same url, is a photo transmitted second by second from PiCamera installed on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Ya then you can download that images using Android Query as I have mentioned. Create one method and paste my code there. Just replace your imageview and your image url. It will refreshed automatically.

Comment: @pratik are you sure AQuery lib automatic() refresh image from URL ?

Comment: just set your image everytime when new image downloaded. That means it will do refresh

Comment: I got this error with AQuery: Execution failed for task':app:dexDebug'

Comment: i thnk problem in your code...post yr code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend a different way that works like a charm: Android Query.

You can download that JAR file from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list)

```
AQuery androidAQuery = new AQuery(this);
```

As an example:

```
androidAQuery.id(YOUR IMAGEVIEW).image(YOUR IMAGE TO LOAD, true, true, getDeviceWidth(), ANY DEFAULT IMAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW);
```

It's very fast and accurate, and using this you can find many more features like animation when loading, getting a bitmap (if needed), etc.